# error deploying entitlement process via ant migration tool and changeset

Tags: deployment, sandbox, ant, change-set, entitlements

I'm trying to deploy a new version of an existing entitlement process from one dev sandbox to a full copy sandbox using the ant migration tool.

```
<Package>
    <types>
        <members>test team entitlement process_v7</members>
        <name>EntitlementProcess</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

Retrieving the metadata works, but when I try to deploy to the full copy sandbox I get the following error.

```
entitlementProcesses/test team entitlement process_v7.entitlementProcess -- Error: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-20515:
    ORA-06512: at "DOPEY.CMILESTONE", line 152
    ORA-06512: at line 1


    {call cMilestone.insert_detail(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}

    {call cMilestone.insert_detail(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
```

Does the ant migration tool not work with entitlements? Is changesets the only way of deploying?

**EDIT:**

I just tried deploying using a changeset and I am getting the same error that I got using the ant migration tool

[image: Deploy Fail]

**EDIT 2:**

The exception I am seeing, like OP's is as follows:

```
entitlementProcesses/customer_support_v1.entitlementProcess -- Error: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-20515: 
    ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CMILESTONE", line 152
    ORA-06512: at line 1


    {call cMilestone.insert_detail(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}

    {call cMilestone.insert_detail(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
```

Comment: I'm also encountering this, deploying from a dev sandbox to a partial sandbox - so far, the workaround has been to omit the entitlement process from the package. I am going to open a ticket and will update if I find a resolution.

Comment: As OP stated, this issue is also reproducible using a change set. I opened a case with support; it was closed because the agent deemed it a "development issue." I assume this was because Ant was mentioned, so I opened a second case and made it explicitly clear that this was in the context of a change set and not dev-related. The agent immediately closed the case as "dev related" - gotta love non-premier support

Comment: Have you tried removing spaces from entitlement process name? This looks like some inner miss of encoding. What happens if you create a new entitlement process with name without spaces and try to deploy that?

Comment: @Patlatus this was a really good suggestion - mine also had a space in the name, like OP's. I removed the space and retrieved + attempted deploy again, and still the same issue. Really appreciate the suggestion though!

Comment: @BrianMansfield hmmm... should one try to remove underscores as well? maybe if we give some very simple name to it like "a" or "b" it might work

Comment: or the problem might be in the content itself... it might be helpful if you post the xml file for the entitlement, maybe it has some data which is not properly escaped by both ANT Migration Tool and Changesets

Answer (score 4):

After 3+ weeks back and forth with support, we finally reached developer support and they were able to reproduce this exception and look at their internal logs.

It turns out that in the source org, we had increased the milestone limit to 50. In the target org, the limit was still 25. The `EntitlementProcess` we were attempting to deploy had over 25 milestones associated with it, so we were thrown a seven-dwarf exception.

Syncing the milestone limit between the two orgs (or alternatively, reducing the number of milestones in the entitlement process) should resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I Finally found why my Entitlement process isn't working for retrieve in Ant.
It was giving this message "Entity of type 'EntitlementProcess' named "Solar_Cross_Financeiro_Contestacao" cannot be found.

My solution -> Appears that have a bug in Salesforce/Salesforce Ant that you can't name the process with UPPERCASE characters. You need to rename in metadata(Ant) for example, if your process name is My_Process_Details, you need to write in metadata "my_process_details_v4"(number of version) doing this, the command works as expected.